# Two left columns and main content in right column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

**Problem:**

Trying to create a layout using Bootstrap 3 that consist of two columns on the left of the page and one main column to the right of the two columns. The two columns on the left should be on top of each other.

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <h3>Left column 1</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content" id="gallery"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <h3>Left column 2</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content" id="gallery"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <h3>Main column</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 280px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

Current code produce two columns next to each other on top the main column.

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: if possible give a snapshot of the output.

Comment: Add the image of ur desired o/p in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a div with class `.col-sm-4` and `.col-sm-8` respectively as the parent div for the two column layout you want to use and then create the desired widgets within those divs.

**Check out my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nJtX9/9/**

Please make sure to **enlarge the results window** to see the correct layout. Otherwise it will stack the div containers for responsive purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 col-md-4 meaning is taking 8 columns already + using col-md-8 = 16 columns, bear in mind bootstrap can contain 12 columns per row,

so the way to go around this is use col-md-2 instead of col-md-4

Hope i make this clear.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit but now Left column 1 and 2 are next to each other, not under each other.

Comment: So you want 3 rows ? then use ( not sure what you mean ) i guess this is what you want.

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   </div>
</div>

Comment: I want two columns under each other on the left and one column to the right of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:gray">
                <div class="row" style="background-color:aliceblue">
                    <h1>col1----row1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>col1----row2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: aqua">
                <h1>col2-----row<br />col2---row<br />col2---row</h1>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: This image show the sample]

Comment: click "enter image discription here" link to see the output

Comment: A good answer explains how it answers the question so not only the person asking benefits, but others later coming across this also benefit.